# Yii2 include assets after code generated by widget

Tags: yii2, yii-extensions, yii-widgets

How to include my .js files after javascript code generated by Datepicker widget in view file.

```
            echo DatePicker::widget([
                'name'  => 'datepicker--2',
                'id' => 'datepicker--2',
                'clientOptions' => [
                    'showOtherMonths' => true,
                    'maxDate' => '+ 0d',
                    'showOtherMonths' => true,
                    'selectOtherMonths' => true,
                ]
            ]);
```

My asset bundle:

```
namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class ChartsAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $js = [
        'js/charts.js',
        'js/charts-init.js',
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\jui\JuiAsset',
        'yii\web\JqueryAsset',
    ];
}
```

What I'm getting on my page source:

```
...
<script src="/new/js/charts.js"></script>
<script src="/new/js/charts-init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function () {
$('#datepicker--2').datepicker($.extend({}, {"showOtherMonths":true,"maxDate":"+ 0d","selectOtherMonths":true,"dateFormat":"M d, yy"}));
});</script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there any reason that you want your scripts to be loaded after the `jQuery(document).ready()` code generated by the `DatePicker`? The code in there only gets executed after the DOM has loaded anyway, including the script tags that load your js files.

Comment: ^ what he asked, what problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: @deacs charts-init.js contains jQuery(document).ready() too and need to access initiated datepicker.

Comment: When you register your js file. Define the depends
$this->registerJsFile(Yii::$app->homeUrl .'test.js', [
  'depends' => [yii\web\JqueryAsset::className()],
  'position' => \yii\web\View::POS_END
 ]);
dependent on your datepicker assets class like i did for jqueryAssets

Answer (score 4):

With yii2, you have options to define the [position](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-view.html#PH_BODY_BEGIN_detail) (HEAD, BEGIN OR END) of the client scripts with in the  the document. This can be achieved by doing something like this

```
public $jsOptions = [
        'position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD
 ];
```

**Or Using [This.](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-view.html#registerJsFile()-detail)**

Comment: What should I do in my case? How can I put widget scripts between my scripts?

Answer (score 2):

Create `BaseAssets` like this:

```
namespace app\assets;

class BaseAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = '@resources'; // @app/resources
    public $css = [];  
    public $js = [];    
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\jui\JuiAsset',
        'yii\web\JqueryAsset',
    ];         
    public $jsOptions = [ 'position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD ];
}
```

And your `Assets`:

```
namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class ChartsAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $js = [
        'js/charts.js',
        'js/charts-init.js',
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'app\assets\BaseAssets',        
    ];
    public $jsOptions = [ 'position' => \yii\web\View::POS_END ];
}
```